# Optimise many-to-many join

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables: `posts` and `tags` and `posts_tags` which forms a many-to-many relationship between `posts` and `tags`.

Having a tag with milions of posts. How could I effectively retrieve the first 10 posts ordered by its name which contain the tag?

<s>Schema:</s>

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    post_time   TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE posts_tags (
    post_id     INT REFERENCES posts(id),
    tag_id      INT REFERENCES tags(id)
);
```

I tried the query below but it's too slow.

```
WITH tag_id AS (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name = 'tag_which_has_milions_of_posts'),
    post_ids AS (SELECT post_id FROM posts_tags WHERE tag_id = (SELECT id FROM tag_id)) 
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ANY(SELECT post_id FROM post_ids)
ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 10;
```

UPDATE:

**I've change "post_time" to "name" to make it easier to generate test data**.

Full schema (including indexes and test data):

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE posts_tags (
    tag_id    INT REFERENCES tags(id),
    post_id   INT REFERENCES posts(id)
);

CREATE INDEX ON posts(name);
CREATE INDEX ON tags(name);
CREATE INDEX ON posts_tags(post_id);
CREATE INDEX ON posts_tags(tag_id);

INSERT INTO posts (name) SELECT generate_series(1, 1000000)::TEXT;
INSERT INTO tags (name) SELECT generate_series(1, 1000000)::TEXT;
INSERT INTO posts_tags (tag_id, post_id) SELECT generate_series(1, 1000000), generate_series(1, 1000000);
INSERT INTO posts_tags (tag_id, post_id) SELECT 1, generate_series(2, 1000000);
INSERT INTO posts_tags (tag_id, post_id) SELECT 2, generate_series(400000, 600000);
```

Query (from McNets's answers):

```
select posts.* from posts_tags pt 
    inner join tags on tags.id = pt.tag_id 
    inner join posts on posts.id = pt.post_id 
where tags.name = '2' 
order by posts.name desc 
limit 10;
```

Query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=288.72..288.73 rows=2 width=10) (actual time=893.348..893.349 rows=10 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=288.72..288.73 rows=2 width=10) (actual time=893.346..893.348 rows=10 loops=1)
        Sort Key: posts.name DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.28..288.71 rows=2 width=10) (actual time=0.061..694.762 rows=200002 loops=1)
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..287.78 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.051..78.175 rows=200002 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using tags_name_idx on tags  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: (name = '2'::text)
                    ->  Index Scan using posts_tags_tag_id_idx on posts_tags pt  (cost=0.43..278.44 rows=89 width=8) (actual time=0.009..54.474 rows=200002 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: (tag_id = tags.id)
            ->  Index Scan using posts_pkey on posts  (cost=0.42..0.46 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=200002)
                    Index Cond: (id = pt.post_id)
Planning time: 0.562 ms
Execution time: 893.428 ms
(14 rows)
```

Comment: It's not very easy to suggest performance improvements without important details like how many rows the tables involved in the query have, what indices there are, and without seeing the current execution plan.

Comment: @AndriyM I've just updated my question. Sorry for being late.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not a PostgreSQL expert, so I won't be able to help much here. I just happen to know that those points are frequently requested on questions about query performance. Thanks for the update.

Comment: In light of your new "test data" I think you should delete all queries that are not written in terms of your test data. You're confusing yourself and others.

Comment: So, your query runs under a second.  What would be an acceptable performance?  Also, an `ANALYZE posts_tags;` seems necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Has a standard join structure less performance?

```
SELECT posts.*
FROM posts_tags pt
     inner join tags ON tags.id = pt.tags_id
     inner join posts ON posts.id = pt.post_id
WHERE tags.name = 'some tag'
ORDER by posts.name DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's still slow though. I think the query need to join all posts before it can do ordering and then take the first 10 rows. So postgres needs to scan through all of those posts. That makes it unavoidable slow.

Comment: Do you have any index with both `posts.id` and `posts.post_time`? Is `posts.post_time` defined to be `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Do you know any way to work around it? Or am I missing somethings?

Comment: Yes. I've created index on `posts.post_time` and `posts_tags.post_id` and `posts_tags.tag_id` and `tags.name`.

Comment: Is `tags.name` propery indexed? Is it declared `NOT NULL`?

Comment: It's just an example that I made up because of curiosity. They all aren't declared NOT NULL. But does it matter?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I see that it amounts to the same thing as McNets' answer since you have created the indexes on the two foreign keys in posts_tags.  I would only add that you might want to try to join to a query on posts that limits the time, rather than joining to the entire posts table, and consider having an index on time if time selectivity is going to be a continuing major need.

Comment: The NOT NULL should not matter.  What is making it slow is that you are not going to have any query that can traverse millions of rows and not take a bit of time.

Comment: @AgapwIesu I think (haven't tried yet) if I had an array of tags in `posts` table: `tags TEXT[]` then I could index it with `post_time` so the query would be fast. But it feels weird when I can't do anything likes that on traditional many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Which is the `SELECT` time you are expecting? (I'm making a few simulations in the range of a few millions rows, and response times is in the range of seconds, even if execution plans involve 2 `nested loop inner joins`. I guess that any futher improvement means *denormalizing* your data (moving a copy of the `post_time` to the `posts_tags` table).

Comment: I'd be happy if the `SELECT` would take just fews ms. I guess you're right. Thanks for the answer.